# If $X \sim U(0,1)$ and $Y \sim U(0,X)$, what is the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

**Problem:** Let $X  \sim U(0,1)$, $Y \sim U(0,X)$. Which is the joint distribution $f(x,y)$?

**Attempt:** $$\mathbb P(X \leq a, Y \leq b) = \mathbb E(\mathbb P (Y \leq b \mid X=x \leq a)) = \int_0^a \frac b x \, dx $$ which is of course a problem!

Thanks!

Comment: Can we assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables?

Comment: @Wolfy well I see them dependent!

Comment: Work directly with the PDF of $X$ and the conditional PDF of $Y$, namely, $$f_X(x)=\mathbf 1_{0<x<1}\qquad f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)=\frac1x\mathbf 1_{0<y<x}$$ hence $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)=\frac1x\mathbf 1_{0<y<x<1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the two random variables the joint distribution is obtained by integrating the joint probability density over the rectangle $[0,a] \times [0,b]$.  Note that the density is zero when $y > x$ and outside the rectangle $[0,1]\times [0,1]$.

If $b \geqslant a$, then

$$F(a,b) = \int_0^a \left( \int_0^x \frac{1}{x} \, dy\right) \, dx = a$$

otherwise, if $b < a$, then

$$F(a,b) = \int_0^b \left( \int_0^x \frac{1}{x} \, dy\right) \, dx + \int_b^a \left( \int_0^b \frac{1}{x} \, dy\right) \, dx = b + b \log(a/b)$$

Comment: Why the joint pfd is that one?

Comment: The marginal pdf of $X$ is $1$ since $X \sim U(0,1)$.  The conditional density of $Y$ given $X = x$ is $1/x$ since conditionally $Y \sim U(0,x)$ and the joint density is the product.  You were already trying to use $1/x$ above.

Answer (score 1):

Since $X\sim U(0,1)$ and $X = x$, let $Y$ have uniform distribution on the interval $(0,x)$. So we have 
$$f_{X}(x) = 1 \ \ \ 0\leq x \leq 1$$
and 
$$f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{1}{x} \ \ \ 0\leq y \leq x$$
Hence the joint density is

$$f(x,y) = f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_{X}(x) = \frac{1}{x}\times 1 = \frac{1}{x} \ \ \ 0\leq x \leq 1, 0\leq y \leq x$$