# What's this "$U(0,U(0,1))$" distribution with density function $p(x)=-\ln x$ called?

Tags: probability-distributions, reference-request, terminology, uniform-distribution

This distribution seems natural to study (because of how it arises and its simple PDF), but I had trouble searching the web for it and couldn't find it in [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions). Is there a name for it?

See e.g.:

- [If $X\sim U(0,1)$ and $Y\sim U(0,X)$ what is the density (distribution) function $f_Y(y)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1740535)
- [If $X \sim U(0,1)$ and $Y \sim U(0,X)$, what is the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2627008)
- https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4602057

Comment: It's important to limit the support to $(0,1]$.

Comment: I find it more helpful to define it as the product of two independent $U(0,1)$-distributed random variables $Y = X \cdot (Y/X)$ rather than defining $Y$ as distributed conditional on $X$.  In this way, it's more natural to take the negative logarithm (sums are better behaved than products in the theory) and study $-\log Y \sim \Gamma(2,1)$.  You can always move it back by applying $x \mapsto e^{-x}$ to the suitable Gamma.

Comment: @lcv I see that $\ln0$ is undefined (which I interpret in this case as telling us that $\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac1hP(Y<h)=\infty$), but I'm not sure I understand the significance of your comment beyond that. Does whether we consider $0$ to be in the support change the definition of the distribution?

Comment: Oh no, I'm saying something quite simple. I suppose your density is actually $\ln(x) 1_{(0,1]}$ or it wouldn't be normalizable.